# Why do I keep getting 'Cannot find or open the PDB file' messages in Visual Studio and how to fix?

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio Community 2015.

When I initially ran my code, it would give me numerous errors saying “***Module is optimized and the debugger option ‘Just My Code’ is enabled.”*** 
I would receive no output otherwise.

What I tried was:

- Clicking ‘Tools - Options -Debugging - General’ then unchecking the box ‘Enable Just My Code’

When I did this and cleaned my solution, then reran it, that error went away, but was replaced by a new error:

***“Cannot find or open the PDB file”*** and at the bottom says ***“Symbols Loaded”***

I do not know why this is occurring or how to fix it. 
Here is what I have tried:

- Clicking ‘Tools - Options - Debugging - Symbols’ then checking the box for Microsoft Symbol Servers.
- Clicking ‘Tools - Options - Debugging - Symbol’” then UNchecking the box for Microsoft Symbol Servers.
- Clicking ‘Tools - Options - Debugging - Output Window’ then turning “Module Load Messages” off (**but I did not like this because it seems like it was avoiding the issue, not fixing it. Plus, my program ran, but produced no output.)
- Closing program and restarting

**Here is my code, for reference:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace practice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter comma separated numbers: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            var numbers = input.Split(',');

            // Assume the first number is the max 
            var max = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[0]);

            foreach (var str in numbers)
            {
                var number = Convert.ToInt32(str);
                if (number > max)
                    max = number;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Max is " + max); 

        }        
    }
}
```

I don’t know what to do. Please help.

Comment: It is an entirely normal diagnostic from the debugger, you won't have the PDB files of the assemblies in the .NET framework.  Which is fine, you are not trying to debug the framework.  Don't do anything but focus on debugging your own code.

Comment: So should I re-enable "Just My Code"? 
I know my own code works, but it never shows the output, just those messages. How do I correct that?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the last curly brace of Main() so you can look at the output.  Or add the traditional "Press any key to continue" logic.  Or press Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score -1):

So, while I don't necessarily understand all the details, I did manage to somehow "fix" my problem.

Here is what I did:

Basically, I make sure “Optimize” is unchecked in the Program ‘properties’. (It is unchecked, by default). 
Then, in the ‘tools-options-debugging-symbols’ section, I did check “Microsoft Server Symbols.” (I have read the reasons not to, such as the opportunity to reverse engineer your code, but I do not plan on publishing or sending my code anywhere so that shouldn’t be an issue. Plus, IF I ever did, I read about the stripped PDB option and would try that. )

I selected it because my output kept saying “Cannot open or find PDB file.”
It was bugging me to see it and try to ignore it.

And I’m not exactly sure if this made/makes any difference, but I unchecked “Enable Just My Code”…I still don’t know what it really does/affects despite trying to read up on it a bit. *(If any one can explain what it does/affects and why I do/don't need to use it, I'd appreciate it!)*

Then, I clicked to “Clean Solution” and then clean the program itself before rebuilding and running. This time, it did show my output in the console, and I did see a bunch of messages in the output box, but this time they all said “Symbols Loaded” and I figure that is not a bad message, so I have left well-enough alone for now.

I am posting this just in case anyone else has this issue and might benefit from what I tried.

Comment: If someone is going to mark my answer down, I'd appreciate knowing why because if my answer is incorrect or there is something better I could do, I would benefit from knowing, especially as I stated that I really didn't understand.